# Kafka - why new topic partition leader is not elected?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka cluster of 3 nodes. When Node #3 dies, my `_schemas` topic stops functioning properly and I see this:

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic _schemas --describe
Topic:_schemas  PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:cleanup.policy=compact
    Topic: _schemas Partition: 0    Leader: -1      Replicas: 3,2   Isr: 2
```

So it seems that node #3 is dead and that is what `Leader: -1` refers to. But why doesn't Kafka just continue working as usual, assigning `Node #2` as the new leader and replicating the data to `#1` so that we have 2 in sync replicas?

The error I see in the kafka logs:

```
kafka.common.NotAssignedReplicaException:
Leader 3 failed to record follower 2's position -1 since the replica is not 
recognized to be one of the assigned replicas 3 for partition <loop over many partitions>
```

Comment: are you hitting https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5758

Comment: Kafka Version I am on is `0.11`, similar error, but how do I tell?

Comment: Restarting other nodes (1 and 2) actually helped to resolve the issue

Comment: Check controller.log to see what went wrong and why controller did not select new leader for [_schemas,0].

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by restarting the controller broker. every kafka cluster has a broker been elected to controller so it will coordinate leader election. our case is that controller stuck. in order to find which broker is controller, you can just go to your zkCli.sh to access into your zookeeper which your kafka cluster uses, and then do `get /controller`, you will see brokerId there. 
I fixed this easily by restarting the controller broker, good luck.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a cluster of 3 kafka brokers, and you have only 1 partition  for your topic, it means that you have only `one` leader, and you are producing data and working only against this broker.

If you want kafka to:

> continue working as usual, assigning Node #2 as the new leader

You should create your topic with 3 partitions, each broker will be leader in other partitions, and if one of the brokers will fail down you'll be able to write to other partitions.

see example of running `./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic _schemas --describe`:

```
Topic:_schemas    PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:retention.ms=14400000
Topic: _schemas   Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2 Isr: 2
Topic: _schemas   Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
Topic: _schemas   Partition: 2    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
```

In this example you can see that `_schemas` has 3 partitions meaning all 3 brokers are leaders of that topic each on different partition, s.t broker 2 is leader on partition 0 and broker 0 and broker 1 are followers on partition 0.

Comment: Yes, but in your case, if node#0 dies, a third of the data is lost, so it is not acceptable. In my case, I have replication factor = 2, so if the leader goes down, all of the data is still available on the other node, that I expect to be elected as a new leader and this data synced then to the remaining node.